# how to draw an achartengine TimeSeries with points but no lines between them?

Tags: achartengine

I currently fake this feature by setting the XYSeriesRenderer color to white:

```
    final XYSeriesRenderer goodEventSeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    goodEventSeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    goodEventSeriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
    goodEventSeriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);
    goodEventSeriesRenderer.setAnnotationsTextSize(textSize + 2);
    goodEventSeriesRenderer.setAnnotationsColor(Color.GREEN);
```

I tried calling `setLineWidth(0)`, which typically works in other graphical systems to zilch the line, but that just returned hairlines between the points.

So how do I get a time series chart where some TimeSeries have lines between their points, and some don't? I run with achartengine compiled into my program, not from a jar file, so feel free to help me hack the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the diff of the changes to AChartEngine to allow `.setLineWidth(0)` to zilch the lines:

```
--- a/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/AbstractChart.java
+++ b/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/AbstractChart.java
@@ -302,6 +302,7 @@ public abstract class AbstractChart implements Serializable {
     Path path = new Path();
     int height = canvas.getHeight();
     int width = canvas.getWidth();
+    float strokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();

     float[] tempDrawPoints;
     if (points.size() < 4) {
@@ -310,7 +311,10 @@ public abstract class AbstractChart implements Serializable {
     tempDrawPoints = calculateDrawPoints(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2),
         points.get(3), height, width);
     path.moveTo(tempDrawPoints[0], tempDrawPoints[1]);
-    path.lineTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
+    if (strokeWidth > 0.0f)
+      path.lineTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
+    else
+      path.moveTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);

     int length = points.size();
     for (int i = 4; i < length; i += 2) {
@@ -323,7 +327,10 @@ public abstract class AbstractChart implements Serializable {
       if (!circular) {
         path.moveTo(tempDrawPoints[0], tempDrawPoints[1]);
       }
-      path.lineTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
+      if (strokeWidth > 0.0)
+        path.lineTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
+      else
+        path.moveTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
     }
     if (circular) {
       path.lineTo(points.get(0), points.get(1));
diff --git a/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/LineChart.java b/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/LineChart.java
index 55365e3..be0937b 100644
--- a/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/LineChart.java
+++ b/app/src/main/java/org/achartengine/chart/LineChart.java
@@ -81,7 +81,8 @@ public class LineChart extends XYChart {
   public void drawSeries(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, List<Float> points, XYSeriesRenderer renderer,
       float yAxisValue, int seriesIndex, int startIndex) {
     float lineWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
-    paint.setStrokeWidth(renderer.getLineWidth());
+    float lineWidth1 = renderer.getLineWidth();
+    paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth1);
     final FillOutsideLine[] fillOutsideLine = renderer.getFillOutsideLine();

     for (FillOutsideLine fill : fillOutsideLine) {
@@ -227,8 +228,13 @@ public class LineChart extends XYChart {
   public void drawLegendShape(Canvas canvas, SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer, float x, float y,
       int seriesIndex, Paint paint) {
     float oldWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
-    paint.setStrokeWidth(((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer).getLineWidth());
-    canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + SHAPE_WIDTH, y, paint);
+    float lineWidth = ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer).getLineWidth();
+
+    if (lineWidth > 0.0) {
+      paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
+      canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + SHAPE_WIDTH, y, paint);
+    }
+
     paint.setStrokeWidth(oldWidth);
     if (isRenderPoints(renderer)) {
       pointsChart.drawLegendShape(canvas, renderer, x + 5, y, seriesIndex, paint);
```